# Are inventory slots shared?

Tags: no-mans-sky

Are the inventories between my exosuit, starship and exocraft shared?

If I want to craft an item in my exosuit inventory and I have parts spread across all three inventories will the game know this and pull the items it needs, assuming they're in range.

Or do I have to transfer items from my exocraft to my suit, then to my ship or vice versa?

Comment: Back in release days you needed to be in proximity to all inventories you wanted to access. No idea how it works nowadays, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I decided to test this for myself, and placed some iron into my Starship.  My Exosuit had no iron on it whatsoever.  I attempted to craft a Carite Sheet, and it allowed me to do so.  As expected, the iron that was within my starship was now gone.

It appears then that having supplies scattered across different inventories will still allow you to craft something in your exosuit, so long as you are close enough.  If you are out of range of whichever craft has the items you need, you won't be able to craft it unless you get closer (the item will be grayed out in the crafting menu). As said in the comments, I believe this is how the game has always been, but it's been a while since I've played it, so I decided to try for myself to be sure.

Comment: Based on the [inventory wiki](https://nomanssky.gamepedia.com/Inventory), you can transfer items from your ship to your inventory if you are in 25 secs walking distance. I'm guessing the crafting distance would be the same

Comment: Although this doesn't count storage containers if you're at your base though.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it has always been like this.  You can also craft things in your ship inventory from anywhere.  So, if you're far away and your launch thruster doesn't work, for instance, you can just collect the resources and fix it from any distance.